# Get all solutions to a query, that has no alternatives when queried

Tags: random, prolog

This may seem like an odd question that could simply be answered by the `findall/3` predicate. However my problem is a little deeper than that.

So I have a predicate called `ran_num/1` that returns one of five random numbers (that is I do not know what the numbers could be but there are only 5 of them).

When I run the predicate it returns this output as an example:

```
?- ran_num(X).
X = 2
?-
```

Note that there are no alternative answers, pressing `;` will do nothing. Prolog is awaiting another query command.

If I run findall on this the result is:

```
?- findall(X, ran_num(X), L).
L = [2]
?-
```

Is there an inbuilt predicate or method I can implement that will get me all the possible numbers that can be generated? So for example I can get a list which is [2,60,349,400,401].

Assume I cannot change the `ran_num/1` predicate to give me alternatives.

Comment: Assuming the number is randomly generated, is it not the case that you'd have to call the function an infinite number of times to ensure that all possible results have been returned?

Comment: @RichO'Kelly I would say that's certainly the case! However there is a finite number of unique answers and I felt this changes proceedings slightly. I have also edited my question slightly to avoid some triviality.

Comment: Whilst you know the range, how would this method be able to determine it? I believe that if someone comes up with a generic way for your predicate to do so, they'd have solved the halting problem (which is beyond the reach of most SO users).

Comment: @RichO'Kelly Yes, you're totally right. I was thinking that when Prolog calls the predicate and returns an answer it arrived at that answer deterministically through a certain route and that it could backtrack for alternatives. But it's not a true alternative, which is the problem I'm faced with.

Comment: It is not clear how your `ran_num/1` behaves. Does it _randomly_ pick one out of the five possible values? Are you getting them in the same order? Do _you_ know how many values it can have? Can _you_ know in what order you will get them? Are you seeding it with a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you face is that `ran_num/1` is deterministic as far as the interpreter is concerned. It doesn't know that calling it again may yield a different result.

Prolog's `random_between/3` works like that, so I've defined your predicate `ran_num/1` as follows.

```
ran_num(X) :-
    random_between(1, 5, Y),
    ran_num_mapping(Y, X).

ran_num_mapping(1,   2).
ran_num_mapping(2,  60).
ran_num_mapping(3, 349).
ran_num_mapping(4, 400).
ran_num_mapping(5, 401).
```

This is deterministic, like your example.

---

So `ran_num/1` returns one of five *different* numbers at random and we want to know these five numbers. This means we need to keep calling `ran_num/1` until we have a set of five numbers.

We can define a set `S` of length `N`.

```
is_set_of_length(S, N) :-
    is_set(S),
    length(S, N).
```

So we have all "ran_num"s if we have a set of length 5.

```
get_all_ran_nums(Y, Y) :-
    is_set_of_length(Y, 5), !.
```

Otherwise, we get another ran_num, add it to the set, and check again.

```
get_all_ran_nums(L, T) :-
    ran_num(X),
    ord_add_element(T, X, Lout),
    get_all_ran_nums(L, Lout).
```

We need to start this with an empty list.

```
get_all_ran_nums(X) :-
    get_all_ran_nums(X, []).
```

And this yields our result.

```
?-
get_all_ran_nums(X).
X = [2, 60, 349, 400, 401]
?-
```

Please note that the cut in the first clause of `get_all_ran_nums/2` is necessary, otherwise we can keep backtracking but getting the same result. Since we can keep generating ran_nums and adding them to the set; if they are already *in* the set, `ord_add_element/3` will still succeed.

Also note that, since the numbers are generated at random, *in theory* this could keep running for any length of time and not getting the fifth number we need to stop.

Comment: @ZoSal Take a good look at the definition of `ran_num_mapping/2`. I would like to point out that with such a definition, you could just as well grab the possible values directly from there.

Comment: @ZoSal In other words, I understand that you don't want to or cannot change the defintion of `ran_num/1`, and this answer shows how, but a clean solution is still to avoid the unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: It is very improbable that the program does not somehow already contain the possible values to which `ran_num/1` can bind its arguments.

Comment: @Boris The general question remains, how to deal with a predicate that is syntactically deterministic, but semantically nondeterministic.

Comment: Of course, which is why I gave you the +1 etc. But I really have trouble imagining a situation in which a) a predicate has such behaviour **and** b) the programmer cannot get to the possible solutions in any other way. Either you can get all solutions, or you cannot know if there is a finite number of solutions. Can you give an example where both hold?

Comment: @Boris, I've very little experience interfacing Prolog with external sources, but I can imagine the situation comes up in those circumstances.

Comment: Yep, that would be the only possible explanation.

Comment: This is what I thought of doing at first and did not think it was viable due to the _in theory_ part. Thank you for the answer.